# Why could Harry and Lupin practice the patronus on the boggart?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Harry and Lupin could practice the patronus on the boggart, but when Harry was in the final task in the *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, he tried to use the patronus on the boggart, it didn't work and he then moved on to use ridikkilus.

Why could he use a patronus against the boggart, but then not in another?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, his patronus *was* working on the Boggart (blocking it from approaching him) it just wasn't very effective in *pushing it awa*y from him:

> *To make matters even worse, Harry’s Anti-Dementor lessons were not
>   going nearly as well as he had hoped. Several sessions on, he was able
>   to produce an indistinct, silvery shadow every time the
>   Boggart-Dementor approached him, but **his Patronus was too feeble to
>   drive the Dementor away.** All it did was hover, like a
>   semi-transparent cloud, draining Harry of energy as he fought to keep
>   it there. Harry felt angry with himself, guilty about his secret
>   desire to hear his parents’ voices again.*
>
>   <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban**</sup></sub>

By the time we see him use another Patronus on a Boggart, it's become [fully corporeal](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Patronus_Charm) and capable of interacting with solid matter. Instead of hovering like a vague silver cloud it's now quite literally erupting from his wand in the form of a charging stag. Clearly it's a vastly more powerful spell:

> ***A silver stag erupted from the end of Harry’s wand and galloped
>   towards the Dementor, which fell back, and tripped over the hem of its
>   robes …*** Harry had never seen a Dementor stumble. ‘Hang on!’ he
>   shouted, advancing in the wake of his silver Patronus, ‘you’re a
>   Boggart! Riddikulus!’ There was a loud crack, and the shape-shifter
>   exploded in a wisp of smoke. The silver stag faded from sight. Harry
>   wished it could have stayed, he could have used some company … but he
>   moved on as quickly and quietly as possible, listening hard, his wand
>   held high once more.
>   <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire**</sup></sub>

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, Patronuses are effective at pushing away Dementor-Boggarts, but Riddikulus *makes them disappear*? Which makes sense - Patronuses don't even make Dementors disappear, as they can't die. So he used the Patronus to push the Boggart away, but once he realized it was a Boggart, there was a more effective spell he could use.

Comment: @trysis - Yup. The patronus charm has a physical aspect that can prevent a boggart from approaching or, if fully formed actually knock the boggart away but it doesn't dispel them.

Comment: I suspect a Patronus is effective as a physical barrier to many/most things, not just boggarts or dementors.

Comment: @TylerH - A corporeal patronus is literally able to interact with solid matter. Imagine being hit by a charging stag.

Comment: @Richard While I agree, I don't think that's ever mentioned in the books. The references to corporeal patronuses seem to be referring to "fully-formed" (ie having a body vs being a shield or just a wisp of smoke) patronuses rather than "tangible".

Comment: @TylerH - A corporeal patronus was used to throw a Lethifold across the room.

Comment: @Richard Is that an account from Pottermore?

Comment: @TylerH - From 'Fantastic Beasts'; "*I knew that I was about to lose consciousness completely as I suffocated. Desperately. I mustered up my last reserve of energy. Pointing my wand away from myself into the deadly folds of the creature, summoning the memory of the day I had been voted President of the local Gobstones Club. I performed the Patronus Charm.*

*Almost at once I felt fresh air upon my face. I looked up to see that deathly shadow being thrown into the air upon the horns of my Patronus. It flew across the room and slithered swiftly out of sight.*"

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer. It did work the second time, but as someone pointed out, he chose to use the other, more effective spell.

Comment: Can you provide a source that the patronus charm worked on the boggart in the Goblet of Fire?